# Update column in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, information-schema

Let's say I have a column called `partner` in **multiple tables** within one schema:

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'partner';
```

How would I update all columns where value `partner = 100` to `partner = 101`?

Comment: Dynamic SQL - PL/PgSQL, `EXECUTE format(...) USING ...`. Also, if you ever need to do this it's probably a sign of problematic database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-time operation, a `DO` statement executing dynamic SQL should serve just fine:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
FOR _tbl  IN
    SELECT quote_ident(table_name)  -- escape identifier!
    FROM   information_schema.columns
    WHERE  table_schema = 'public'  -- your schema (!!)
    AND    column_name = 'partner'  -- your column name
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%',
-- EXECUTE
  'UPDATE ' || _tbl || ' SET partner = 101 WHERE partner = 100';
END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Inspect the generated code before you comment `RAISE` and uncomment the `EXECUTE`.

This is a largely simplified version of the more versatile function in this related answer with more explanation:

- [Changing all zeros (if any) across all columns (in a table) to... say 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814195/changing-all-zeros-if-any-across-all-columns-in-a-table-to-say-1/9814845#9814845)

Information schema or system catalog?

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)