# drop all tables sharing the same prefix in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I would like to delete all tables sharing the same prefix ('supenh_agk') from the same database, using one sql command/query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop multiple tables in PostgreSQL using a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202135/how-to-drop-multiple-tables-in-postgresql-using-a-wildcard)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To do this in *one* command you need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement (or function):

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
FOR _tbl  IN
    SELECT quote_ident(table_schema) || '.'
        || quote_ident(table_name)      -- escape identifier and schema-qualify!
    FROM   information_schema.tables
    WHERE  table_name LIKE 'prefix' || '%'  -- your table name prefix
    AND    table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'    -- exclude system schemas
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%',
-- EXECUTE
  'DROP TABLE ' || _tbl;  -- see below
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

This includes tables from *all* schemas the current user has access to. I excluded system schemas for safety.

If you do not escape identifiers properly the code fails for any non-standard [identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) that requires double-quoting.
Plus, you run the risk of allowing *SQL injection*. All user input must be sanitized in dynamic code - that includes identifiers potentially provided by users.

**Potentially hazardous!** All those tables are dropped for good. I built in a safety. Inspect the generated statements before you actually execute: comment `RAISE` and uncomment the `EXECUTE`.

If any other objects (like views etc.) depend on a table you get an informative error message instead, which cancels the whole transaction. If you are confident that all dependents can die, too, append [`CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html):

```
  'DROP TABLE ' || _tbl || ' CASCADE;
```

Closely related:

- [Update column in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527231/update-column-in-multiple-tables/27530863#27530863)
- [Changing all zeros (if any) across all columns (in a table) to... say 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814195/changing-all-zeros-if-any-across-all-columns-in-a-table-to-say-1/9814845#9814845)

**Alternatively** you could build on the catalog table [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), which also provides the `oid` of the table and is faster:

```
...
FOR _tbl  IN
    SELECT c.oid::regclass::text  -- escape identifier and schema-qualify!
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE  n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'     -- exclude system schemas
    AND    c.relname LIKE 'prefix' || '%' -- your table name prefix
    AND    c.relkind = 'r'                -- only tables
...
```

System catalog or information schema?

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

How does `c.oid::regclass` defend against SQL injection?

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

**Or** do it all in a **single `DROP` command**. Should be a bit more efficient:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', (
-- EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || string_agg(format('%I.%I', schemaname, tablename), ', ')
   --  || ' CASCADE' -- optional
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables t
   WHERE  schemaname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'     -- exclude system schemas
   AND    tablename LIKE 'prefix' || '%'  -- your table name prefix
   );
END
$do$;
```

Related:

- [Is there a postgres command to list/drop all materialized views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092983/is-there-a-postgres-command-to-list-drop-all-materialized-views/23093450#23093450)

Using the conveniently fitting system catalog `pg_tables` in the last example. And `format()` for convenience. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: Works great !! Thx Erwin.

Comment: Hm I can actually see the DROP TABLE statements in the output, but the tables are not getting deleted. The tables are still there and containing data.. Used first version.

Comment: @Xb74Dkjb: `CASCADE` has been there forever, not related to pg 12. It forces the drop including all dependent objects, which is otherwise prohibited.

Answer (score 15):

Suppose the prefix is 'sales_'

**Step 1:** Get all the table names with that prefix

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'sales_%';
```

**Step 2:** Click the "Download as CSV" button.

**Step 3:** Open the file in an editor and replace **"sales_** with **,sales** 
        and **"** with a space

**Step 4:** `DROP TABLE  sales_regist, sales_name, sales_info, sales_somthing;`

Answer (score 4):

This is sql server command, can you try this one, is it worked in postgres or not. 
This query wil generate the sql script for delete

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE "' || TABLE_NAME || '"' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '[prefix]%'
```

**[EDIT]**

```
begin
    for arow in
      SELECT 'DROP TABLE "' || TABLE_NAME || '"' as col1
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '[prefix]%'
    LOOP
   --RAISE NOTICE '%',    
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || arow ;
END LOOP;
  end;
```

Comment: ok, so something like that:
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME || ';' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'supenh_agk%';

But is there a way to execute the resultant script after it is being generated??... 
I want to use one command for doing it all, instead of copying the resultant code and removing the Quotes (" ") 
Thanks!

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name:- + is also working in sql server 2008 to concat

Comment: + doesn't work in postgres... (the question is around postgres). thanks! 
Is there a way to use 'execute' command as part of postgres query? - so to actually execute the resultant script (the output of what was suggested above)?

Comment: @Roy:- add this in temp table, and loop through each row to execute